# Copy the folder along with parent folder

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I have a simple question, but I am unable to figure out a way to do it. I have a folder called `EDSDK` and it internally contains sub-folders. Now in my ant itself I wish to copy all those files.

i.e.

> EDSDK
>
> - headers
> - dlls

I wish to copy the whole above (including EDSDK). Doing:

```
<fx:fileset dir="." type="data" includes="EDSDK/**"/>
```

copies the internal of `EDSDK` folder but not EDSDK folder itself. What should I do?

PS: above `fx:fileset` is similar to `fileset`

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
<fx:fileset dir="." type="data" includes="EDSDK/"/>
```

does the trick.